# Issues with service instances marked as final in spring-boot controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What are the issues with marking a spring-service instance as final in a spring-controller (sample code below)?

If everything in spring is a singleton by default is this just overkill? Also in case it's relevant the **@autowired** annotation is not being used.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class MyController {
    private final MyService myService;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to make class variables *final* whenever possible. This is why I prefer using constructor-based autowiring:

```
...
private final MyService myService;

@Autowired
public MyClass(MyService myService){
  this.myService = myService;
}
...
```

This way, all injected dependencies can be viewed in one place (the constructor) and it is assured that all these variables are initialized after the class has been instantiated.

*Edit*:
As mentioned in the comments you do not need the `@Autowired` annotation on a single constructor since Spring 4.3

Comment: You don't need `@Autowired` as of Spring 4.3 on a single constructor used for autowiring.

Comment: It is good practice to make class variables final whenever possible. But why?

Comment: Making variables immutable (final) will reduce the likelihood of unwanted modifications (e.g. by another class/public method), will often improve performance and they are thread-safe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Answer (score 0):

If we try and declare an @Autowired field as final, we will get compile error. This is annoying in and of itself, as the field is only being set once anyway! Unless you also annotate it as being @Lazy, Spring tries to resolve your dependencies as part of a DAG during startup, and your field may be the source of a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException due to unexpected circular dependencies.

You can use resolve this by using Constructor Injection and define the dependencies as final. Whenever the class needs a new dependency, you’re forced to add it to the constructor’s parameters. This, in turn, forces you to recognize the number of coupling in our class. Since **final fields** can be initialized in the constructor, our dependencies can be immutable — as they should be!

Constructor Injection is recommended by Spring. 
Please check 
https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required